# How to add function output into a text file?

Tags: python

I have this function to write me a file:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter as tk


 def var_states():
     text_file = open("logfile.txt", "a")
     text_file.write("USER: %s, Variable1: %d\n" % (os.getlogin(),var1.get()))
     text_file.close()

var1 = IntVar()
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="sample text", variable=var1).grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)
```

If I open the .txt file, the output is: USER: WindowsUser, sample text

and I also have this function here:

```
def func(value):
    p = Path(value)
    print(p)
```

value is grabbed from click of a button:

```
popupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(left_frame, tkvar, *choices,command = func)
```

this is simply a drop down menu in tkinter where it shows me a list of directories.

My problem is, how do I get the `func()` to be used in `var_states` for writing the value into file?

Here is what I have tried:

```
def var_states():
    text_file = open("logfile.txt", "a")
    text_file.write("USER: %s, Variable1: %d, Func_return: %s \n" % (os.getlogin(), var1.get(), func.get()))
    text_file.close()
```

here is the full code:

```
from tkinter import *
import glob
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui
import datetime
import time
from pathlib import Path

#date & time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SIGN OFF")
root.minsize(840, 400)

# Frames
left_frame = tk.Frame()
right_frame = tk.Frame()

left_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
right_frame.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)

# Directory
directory = "C:/Users/label/Desktop/Sign off Project/sign off img"
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.jpg"))
tkvar.set('...To Sign Off...') # set the default option

# On change dropdown callback.
def change_dropdown(*args):
    """ Updates label2 image. """
    imgpath = tkvar.get()
    img = Image.open(imgpath)
    img = img.resize((529,361))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label2.image = photo
    label2.configure(image=photo)

def func(value):
    p = Path(value)
    print(p)

#Seperating widgets
choose_label = tk.Label(left_frame, text="Choose your sign off here:")
popupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(left_frame, tkvar, *choices,command = func)
display_label = label2 = tk.Label(left_frame, image=None)
open_button = tk.Button(left_frame, text="Open", command=change_dropdown)

choose_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
popupMenu.grid(row=2, column=1)
display_label.grid(row=3, column=1)
open_button.grid(row=4, column=1)







def user():
    tk.Label(right_frame, text= "User: ", font = 'Helvetica 18 bold').grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = W)
    user_input = os.getlogin()
    tk.Label(right_frame, text = user_input, font='Helvetica 18 bold').grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = N)


user()


def var_states():
    text_file = open("logfile.txt", "a")
    text_file.write("TIME: %s, USER: %s, One %d, Two %d, Three %d, Four %d, Five %d, Six %d, Seven %d, Eight %d, Nine %d, Ten %d, Eleven %d, Twelve %d\n" % (now,os.getlogin(), var1.get(), var2.get(), var3.get(), var4.get(), var5.get(), var6.get(), var7.get(), var8.get(), var9.get(), var10.get(), var11.get(), var12.get()))
    text_file.close()

#checkboxes
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var4 = IntVar()
var5 = IntVar()
var6 = IntVar()
var7 = IntVar()
var8 = IntVar()
var9 = IntVar()
var10 = IntVar()
var11 = IntVar()
var12 = IntVar()

tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Ingredients present in full (any allergens in bold with allergen warning if necessary)", variable=var1).grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="May Contain Statement.", variable=var2).grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Cocoa Content (%).", variable=var3).grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Vegetable fat in addition to Cocoa butter", variable=var4).grid(column = 1, row = 4, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Instructions for Use.", variable=var5).grid(column = 1, row = 5, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Additional warning statements (pitt/stone, hyperactivity etc)", variable=var6).grid(column = 1, row = 5, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Nutritional Information Visible", variable=var7).grid(column = 1, row = 7, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Storage Conditions", variable=var8).grid(column = 1, row = 8, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Best Before & Batch Information", variable=var9).grid(column = 1, row = 9, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Net Weight & Correct Font Size.", variable=var10).grid(column = 1, row = 10, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Barcode - Inner", variable=var11).grid(column = 1, row = 11, sticky = W)
tk.Checkbutton(right_frame, text="Address & contact details correct", variable=var12).grid(column = 1, row = 12, sticky = W)




def save():

    var_states()


tk.Button(right_frame, text = "Save", command = save).grid(column = 1, row = 13, sticky = W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to pass the result of one function into another function?

Comment: @TomDalton yeah thats correct sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make some small changes as follows:

**First**

```
p = None

def func(value):
    global p
    p = Path(value)
    print('req:', p)
```

**Second**

```
def var_states():
    text_file = open("logfile.txt", "a")
    # code changed here
    text_file.write("USER: %s, Variable1: %d, Func_return: %s \n" % (os.getlogin(), var1.get(), p))
    text_file.close()
```

I ran your program and after doing this it's working fine.

Comment: please could you explain the code please? not sure why you have added the variable p to none and print('req:'

Comment: I had initialized the variable `p` with `None` and declared it as `global`. So when the function is called `None` gets replaced with the actual value and since `p` is `gobal` you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: overall, does the code look good? from your point of view? just want to hear feedback

Comment: Honestly, it looks a bit clumsy. You can put things into classes and function, thus adding some modularity in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you are using for storing the path is `p` so if you would like to use it in the `var_states` function you should change the line:

```
text_file.write("USER: %s, Variable1: %d, Func_return: %s \n" % (os.getlogin(), var1.get(), func.get()))
```

to

```
text_file.write("USER: %s, Variable1: %d, Func_return: %s \n" % (os.getlogin(), var1.get(), p))
```

Check that you are calling the function before using `p`, else you will have a `NameError` exception.